# ASP.NET Identity 2: trouble creating Fluent Code First relationships

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET Identity DbContext from scratch (getting rid of the depedency on IdentityDbContext<...>)

Nearly there...but my EF Code First fluent relationships are not yet right.

Table structure *should* come out as:
[image]

but getting more like the following:

[image]

That's even after I defined the `HasForeignKey` explicitly.

My question is...where did I go wrong on the relationships?

Thanks!

The mapping I'm using is the following:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection") //, throwIfV1Schema: false
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }
    ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityRoleMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserClaimMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserLoginMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserRoleMap());

    }
    ...
}
public class IdentityUserClaimMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public IdentityUserClaimMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.UserId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        this.ToTable("Custom_UserClaims");
    }
}
public class IdentityUserLoginMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin>
{
    public IdentityUserLoginMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey });
        this.Property(t => t.LoginProvider).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        this.Property(t => t.ProviderKey).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        this.Property(t => t.UserId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        this.ToTable("Custom_UserLogins");
    }
}
public class IdentityRoleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityRole>
{
    public IdentityRoleMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.Id).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        this.Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        this.ToTable("Custom_Roles");
        this
            .HasMany(x => x.Users)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleId);

    }
}

public class IdentityUserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityUserMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.Id).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        this.Property(t => t.Email).HasMaxLength(256);
        this.Property(t => t.UserName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        this.ToTable("Custom_Users");

        //Nav:Claims: User can have 1-(0-*) claims
        this
            .HasMany<IdentityUserClaim>(x => x.Claims)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        //Nav:Logins: User can have 1-(0-*) Logins
        this
            .HasMany<IdentityUserLogin>( x => x.Logins)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        //Nav:Roles:
        //Interestingly, appears not to be using a *-* Map statement:
        this
            .HasMany<IdentityUserRole>(x => x.Roles)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
public class IdentityUserRoleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserRole>
{
    public IdentityUserRoleMap()
    {
        this
            .ToTable("Custom_UserRoles")
            .HasKey(x => new {x.UserId, x.RoleId});

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you merely trying to duplicate the mappings?  Or are you actually trying to use ASP.NET Identity without IdentityDbContext?  If the latter, you're going to have some serious issues, because IdentityDbContext encapsulates a lot of other functionality.

Comment: Hi Erik, I like what I'm seeing in the ASP.NET Identity framework -- I'm just investing edge cases. 

One concern I looking into is trying to use it with an existing app whose ApplicationDbContext is already inheriting from some other vendor's DbContext...

Since one can't have two base classes, I'm looking into what can be done if I was in such a scenario. Hence the duplication of the Mapping in a new DbContext.

Comment: I think you're confused about how to use IdentityDbContext.  You only need to put what is necessary for your Identities in your IdentityDbContext.  You would use a separate DbContext for all the other tables you would use.  Thus, there is no reason for there to be a conflict with a pre-existing DbContext.

Comment: Hi Erik, highly probable :-) Up till now, the apps we've worked on use only 1 DbContext (AppDbContext), containing all the app needs (Domain (Todo/etc./Organisation) + AuthN (User/Session/SessionLog). We manage changes via Migrations. There are many relationships between User and other tables (eg: 1-(1-*) towards Org, and all Domain entities have a *-1 relationship to Org.
Are you suggesting that we use two DbContexts? One the IdentityDbIdentity, one the AppDbContext. With IdentityUser defined in both DbContexts (so Org can continue to ref Users?). How does Migrations then work?

Comment: PS: Looking at the source code of IdentityDbContext I didn't see much logic. Mainly mapping. Although a mapping syntax I haven't seen before.

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

(Still trying to understand why HasForeignKey is not kicking in).

Comment: What i'm saying is use the IdentityDbContext only for Identity related functions (or rather, use UserManager, and only use IdentityDbContext when UserManager doesn't provide an easy way to get at the data you need).  Use a separate DbContext for your applications data model, at least when you have compatibility issues like you mentioned.  There is no requirement that you have only one DbContext in an application (although this was trickier to do in older versions of EF, EF6 has fine support for multiple contexts).  Just add your User to your App's context.

Comment: There is no need to map out the full identity data model in your app, since you will likely just be using it as a discriminator in queries.  FYI, that github link is to the vNext version of Identity, so it's a work in progress...

Comment: Lots to think about.
Regarding multiple DbContexts...see a lot of links saying that one DbContext is the way to go in 99% of cases. But maybe this is a case to use 2 -- and manage migrations using the following approach: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html

Comment: regarding the vNext link...oops.

*still* wish I understood why HasForeignKey didn't work. I thought my migration syntax was right :-( oh well... 

Also wondering how i can close this question -- as it's based on using one DbContext, and I have to further research into multiple DbContexts before anything else...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that's annoying.

Turns out that it works fine.

I don't use Sql Server's diagramming tool all that much, and didn't realise that at some point I got it right... but the diagrams kept on being wrong, simply because I didn't Refresh the tables before i selected them. What a waste of time!

Regarding whether to use one or two DbContexts as Erik suggested in the comments, I'll consider it further. For now, I'll play around with using a single DbContext, as all functionality seems to be working fine.

Night.